# File name containing url encoded characters

Tags: html, web, urlencode

I'm trying to access a file uploaded on a website, but this file's name contains url encoded characters (e.g %2E instead ".").

My browser replaces it when I try to access it and so the name is invalid. For example "image%2Epng" becomes "image.png" which doesn't exist on the server, but "image%2Epng" does exist.
Is there a way to access those files ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL encode the *actual* filename

```
http://example.com/image%252Epng
```